# Building custom RPM with boolean BuildsRequires and Requires

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to use boolean logic for my dependencies (https://rpm.org/user_doc/boolean_dependencies.html) in a custom spec file, but I'm running into trouble.

.spec snippet

```
BuildRequires: libxml2-devel, mysql-devel, net-snmp-devel, (mariadb or mariadb-connector-c), rocksdb-devel, zeromq-devel 
Requires: mysql, libxml2, net-snmp, perl, perl-libwww-perl, net-snmp-perl, net-snmp-libs, net-snmp-utils, (mariadb or mariadb-connector-c), rocksdb, rdkafka, libzmq5 >= 4.1.4, protobuf-c
```

error

```
error: line 27: Dependency tokens must begin with alpha-numeric, '_' or '/': BuildRequires: libxml2-devel, mysql-devel, net-snmp-devel, (mariadb or mariadb-connector-c), rocksdb-devel, zeromq-devel
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you using?  RedHat 7 only has 4.11.3; those extensions came in 4.13 and I don't know if RH backported

Comment: I just spoke w/ the OP he's on 4.8. Doesn't appear to have been backported either. We found this post on SF too - https://serverfault.com/questions/299179/can-one-require-this-or-that-package-in-an-rpm-spec-file.

Comment: Whoops, I saw 4.13 and was thinking in decimal rather than semantic versions :facepalm: 4.8 < 4.13